# I am not able to connect to Google Cloud Memory Store from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, redis, spring-data-redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am developing a module with spring boot in my backend where i need to use Redis through GCP Memory Store. I have been searching in forum and even the "oficial documentation" about memory store but i cannot understand how to connect to memory store with my spring boot app.

I found a google code lab but they use a Compute Engine VM to install spring boot and then save and retrieve information from memory store. So i tried to do it like that in my local spring boot but it didnt work because throws an error saying:

**Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 10.1.3.4**

the codelab i mentioned earlier says that you only have to add this line to your application.properties:

```
spring.redis.host=10.1.3.4
```

as well as the annotation @EnableCaching in the main class and @Cachable annotation in the controller method where you try to do something with redis.

the method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
@Cacheable("hello")
public String hello(@PathVariable String name) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

i dont know what else to do. Notice that i am new on this topic of redis and memory store.

Anyone can give me some guidance on this please?

thanks in advance

codelab url: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cache-memorystore#0

Answer (score 0):

See this [documentation](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/cache/memorystore-redis#memorystore-redis-instance) on how to setup **Memorystore Redis** instance.

Included in the documentation is how you can [connect](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/cache/memorystore-redis#connect-to-instance) and test your Memorystore instance from different computing environments.

There's also a step by step [guide](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/cache/memorystore-redis#spring-boot-cache) on how **SpringBoot** can use Redis to cache with annonations.

1. Add the Spring Data Redis starter in your pom.xml if you're using Maven for your project setup.

```js
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Add this configuration in your application.properties file:

```js
spring.redis.host=<MEMORYSTORE_REDIS_IP>

# Configure default TTL, e.g., 10 minutes
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=600000
```

3. Turn on caching capability explicitly with the @EnableCaching annotation:

```js
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
class DemoApplication {
  ...
}
```

4. Once you configured the Spring Boot with Redis and enabled caching, you can use the @Cacheable annotation to cache return values.

```js
@Service
class OrderService {
  private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
  
  public OrderService(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
    this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
  }
  
  @Cacheable("order")
  public Order getOrder(Long id) {
    orderRepository.findById(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Documentation is pretty bad and incomplete, Google must work on it